# How to find which columns in a tibble are numeric or characters?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Is it possible to extract the position of the columns of a `tibble` with respect to their type?

I want to know at which positions the columns are characters . I don't need this information for selecting or filtering (there, I know how to do `select` of `filter`).

I just need the vector with the positions.

Comment: You can do `sapply(tbl, is.character)`.

Comment: If you need position which(sapply(df, is.character))